# Entity Framework Loading unknown number of nested navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity that includes a navigation property with the collection of the said entities, and this cycle might continue for a while.

```cs
    public class Catalog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Catalog> ChildCatalogs { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Products> ChildProducts { get; set; } // Has to stay empty
    }
```

As it stands right now, the code only loads the first child collection and doesn't go any deeper.

```cs
        public Catalog GetCatalog(int id)
        {
            var catalog = Context.Catalogs.Single(x => x.Id == id);
            Context.Entry(catalog)
                .Collection(x => x.ChildCatalogs)
                .Load();

            return catalog;
        }
```

How can I make it recursively go deeper and deeper until every nested navigation property is loaded?

Comment: Did you try setting `Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` to `true` ?

Comment: @Sumitraj I can't do LazyLoading because the entity has another undisclosed navigation property which has to stay empty in this exact case. I'll edit the question to make it obvious.